# I am trying access cloud database of google app engine but can't access it

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, ubuntu-14.04, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am trying acess cloud sql database of google app engine but can't access it

terminal commands--

```
mysql --host=IPv6_ip --user=user-name --password
```

but getting error

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IPv6_ip ' (110)
```

Comment: this `IPv6_ip`, is it really 'IPv6_ip' used as host address or you mean real IP address by that? also, where you're trying to connect from?

Comment: I used here IPv6 address ( Access Control /  IP address )

Comment: from where you're trying to connect?

Comment: What's your score on this site? http://test-ipv6.com/

Comment: Seems that IPv6 is not supported yet

Comment: From terminal of my ubuntu machine using  commands @Igor Artamonov